# What algorithm does a browser like Chrome or Firefox use to zoom images?

Tags: image, google-chrome, image-processing, browser

I have noticed that when I view a image in a browser using either the zoom provided in the setting or on a webpage using style attributes the pixelation is either negligible or un noticable. But when you use programs such as paint or photoshop or windows picture viewer you start to notice pixelation. Does anyone know how the browser zoom its image contents?

[image]

Here is a sample image the one on right is from paint while one on left is when viewing in chrome. The zoom is set at 500%.

Comment: You could try looking at the Firefox source code available from the [developer guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide) and perhaps ask on one of the [mozilla forums](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/forums/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fonts, I believe it has to do with font sizing. Okay, so say you are in a word processor and type something up you increase the font size the text gets bigger. A similar thing happens in a web browser when you zoom in.

On the other hand when you take an image the resolution is set so as you zoom in the the pixels become larger and more noticeable this is called [aliasing](http://www.telacommunications.com/nutshell/pixelation.htm). Many times a program or browser, etc. will try and smooth the edges in the image to make the pixels look less blocky to the eye, this is called anti-aliasing.

As far as the actual algorithms behind behind paint or a web browser go, I am unsure. It may take some more research to find out.